# Send cookie data from parent to iframe

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-tag-manager, setcookie

I am trying to send data from my cookies captured on my website into an iframe.

I have 2 separate Google Tag Manager accounts - one for the iframe and one for my website.

How do I send the cookie data into the iframe?

```html
<noscript>
 <iframe src="https://test/l/xxxxxx/xxxx-xx-xx/xxxx" width="100%" height="500" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var form = 'https://test/l/xxxxxx/xxxx-xx-xx/xxxx';
 var params = window.location.search;
 var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
 var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

 iframe.setAttribute('src', form + params);
 iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
 iframe.setAttribute('height', 500);
 iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
 iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
 iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
 iframe.style.border = '0';

 thisScript.parentElement.replaceChild(iframe, thisScript);
 window.parent.getCookie('gclid');
</script>
```

Comment: You could take a look at cross-window messaging to send the cookie from your parent site to your iframe. https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#cross-window-messaging

Comment: The only way this would be possible would be to send the `iframe window` a message using `window.postMessage()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 2):

You could also access parent window  `window.parent`  within the iframe.

## Illustration

In the main window, assuming you have a cookie called  *id* and you have implemented a utility function called *getCookie* to get cookie value.

### Main Window

```
getCookie('id')  //for instance returns abc
```

### Somewehre in the page loaded by Iframe

```
window.parent.getCookie('id')  //returns same abc  from above
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? Sorry - I am quite new to all of this so my understanding is pretty limited.

Comment: I tried doing what you said but it did not seem to do the trick. I edited my original post above to include the iframe code.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a work for post messages just in the parent window find your iframe with name and send a message:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" name="iframe">

<script>
    let win = window.frames.iframe;
    win.postMessage("message", "*");
</script>
```

And then in the iframe window you can subscribe to that messages

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // your logic for messages
});
```

[Here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-and-window-postmessage-a60c8f6adea9) is example.

Comment: Okay. So I am not 100% sure what I am doing here. The example left me with a few more questions. 

I am unsure of what to put in "message", especially if I have 9 cookies that I am trying to pass over.

Comment: Ok. I'm not completely understand for what reason you would need to pass 9 cookies to iframe window if you have controlled parent window.

Comment: Never mind. I only need to pass one cookie. I honestly don't know what I am doing at all. I tried doing the code up above, but the cookie did not make it into my iframe.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly do you want to implement but that approach is for passing data between windows so that you can read your cookie inside parent window and pass that data to iframe.

Comment: I am trying to pass a ReferringURL cookie to the iframe and have it pass into a hidden form field on my form.